# Multiple list views in a tabbed page - only one renders

Tags: visualforce, rerender, list-view, ui

I have a visualforce page with a tab panel and included enhanced lists under tabs.
Example:

```
<style>
      .activeTab {background-color: #236FBf;  color:white; background-image:none}
      .inactiveTab { background-color: white; color:black; background-image:none}
   </style>




   <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab=" tabdetails" id="AccountTabPanel" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">   



  <apex:tab label="My Neglected Accounts" name="neg" id="neg">

        <apex:enhancedlist type="Account" height="1000" customizable="false"  listid="00BU0000003grMg" />   
   </apex:tab>
```

When I load the page, the first tab renders fine. The other enhanced list tabs always render improperly, as shown. If I click on one of the letters or the ALL portion, the list renders fine. 
Expected and ok result:
[image]

Fail result:
[image]

This happens on every browser. Any suggestions? I could do it with Apex tables but the enhanced lists are faster to customize and already made. Thanks.

Comment: jaw999.. How you solved this issue... if yes pls give ans to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116534/enhancedlists-are-not-rendering-properly-inside-jquery-ui-tabs-or-tabpanel question

Comment: What I have now and is working is even more nested but just one page uses list views on it and it works. Never got any info on why they were loading badly.